Unable to upload photos to iCloud
I have about 12000 phots in my Photos (7.0) "unable to upload" folder.
I can view these photos on my MacBook in seemingly sharp, full resolution.  BUT I cannot:
edit

"Photos cannot load adjustments for this image"

duplicate

"Failed to download assets for duplication"

nor export

"unknown error (50)"

The only method I can use currently is to take a screen shot of a full screen version... one by one!!  Is there any way I can 'recover' these images so that Photo will recognise them.

Did you try selecting the photo and dragging to a folder in your mac?

@Ashwani - thanks for the suggestion.  It didn't work - "unknown error (50)"

Are you able to see "Photos Library.photoslibrary" file in your pictures folder? If so, you can try right clicking on the file and choosing "Show package contents". In that you can find the photos in "Originals" folder. Let me know if it works.

@Ashwani - thanks for your suggestion.  There are nearly 80 000 images in my photo library.  I've no way of telling where in the archive the 'unable to upload' photos are...?

Probably you can move everything out of there, take a backup, delete the original library photos and then start afresh with your backed up photos.
